# What impact does increasing the number of days historical events are stored have on overall Tableau Server performance

Tags: tableau-api

I'm looking at increasing the number of days historical events that are stored in the Tableau Server database from the default 183 to +365 days and I'm trying to understand what the performance impact to Tableau Server itself would be since the database and backup sizes also start increasing. Would it cause the overall Tableau Server running 2019.1.1 over time to slow to a crawl or begin to have a noticeable impact with respect to performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer here depends on some unknowns and makes it pretty subjective:

1. How much empty space is on your PostGres node.
2. How many events typically occur on your server in a 6-12 month period.

Maybe more importantly than a yes or a no (which should be taken with a grain of salt) would be things to consider prior to making the change.

1. Have you found **value** in the 183 default days? Is it worth the risk adding 365? It sounds like you might be doing some high level auditing, and a longer period is becoming a requirement. If that's the case, the answer is that you have no choice but to go ahead with the change. See steps below.
2. Make sure that the change is made in a **Non-prod environment** first. Ideally one with high traffic. Even though you will not get an exact replica - it would certainly be worth the practice in switching it over. Also you want to make sure that Non-prod and prod environments match exactly.
3. Make sure the change is very **well documented**. For example, if you were to change departments without anyone having knowledge of a non-standard config setting, it might make for a difficult situation if ever Support is needed or if there is a question as to what *might* be causing slow behavior.

Things to consider after a change:

1. Monitor the size of backups.
2. Monitor the size of the historical table(s) (See [Data-Dictionary](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/data_dictionary.htm) for table names if not already known.)
3. Be ready to roll back the config change if the above starts to inflate.

Overall:

1. I have not personally seen much *troubleshooting* value from these tables being over a certain number of days (ie: if there is trouble on the server it is usually investigated immediately and not referenced to 365+ days ago.) Perhaps the value for you lies in determining the amount of usage/expansion on Tableau Server.
2. I have not seen this table get so large that it brings down a server or slows it down. Especially if the server is sized appropriately.
3. If you're regularly/heavily working with and examining PostGres data, it may be wise to extract at a low traffic time of the day. This will prevent excess usage from outside sources during peak times.  Remember that adhoc querying of PostGres is Technically unsupported. This leads to awkward situations if things go awry.